# How do i get my columns to display side by side in the command promt when running python code?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, command-prompt

I am curious if their is a way to display my columns of data right beside each other instead of 7 columns and then the remaining columns below.

This is the output

```
   aaaaaaaa  bbbbbbbb  cccccccc  dddddddd  eeeeeeee  ffffffff  gggggggg  \
1         1         2         3         4         5         6         7
2         1         2         3         4         5         6         7
3         1         2         3         4         5         6         7

   hhhhhhhh  iiiiiiii
1         8         9
2         8         9
3         8         9
Press any key to continue . . .
```

This is the code

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame(index=['1','2','3'])

df['aaaaaaaa'] = 1
df['bbbbbbbb'] = 2
df['cccccccc'] = 3
df['dddddddd'] = 4
df['eeeeeeee'] = 5
df['ffffffff'] = 6
df['gggggggg'] = 7
df['hhhhhhhh'] = 8
df['iiiiiiii'] = 9



print (df.head())
```

Comment: Yes it's possible. Please show how you are generating the lists so that we can help you make the output correct.

Comment: I added the code I am loading data from yahoo finance into a dataframe

Comment: Looks like pandas reads the width of the terminal and uses that. Try changing the console buffer size. Left-click the icon at the top-left of the window. Properties -> Layout -> Screen buffer size. Set the width to a higher number (say 120 or 150). If you want the window to be larger too (instead of showing a scollbar) change the numbers under Window Size to match the buffer settings. These settings should be associated with the executable, so should be reapplied automatically when you restart.

Comment: I set the Screen buffer size higher in the layout tab to 150 then 200, but got the same results

Comment: The window size did work, my window appeared bigger but the columns were still the same

Comment: I changed the code to make it easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

Were you trying to combine two different csv files? If so you need to use the append method. [DataFrame.append](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

Comment: I was not necessary try to combine two csv. I was first trying to get the min and the max of the index and then applying it as a filter, and that was the only way it seemed to work. I know there is a better way but it works for now, also I just erased that code and replaced it with something that is easier

Comment: @ZacAttack pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False)